How to do Custom Authentication in Framer Website
TLDR: Can software like Auth0 be easily integrated in a Framer website?
I am new to web dev, I am making a website in Framer, which has a nice GUI and some coding elements. While I wouldn't call this actual web dev, as  I don't know what's going on under the hood, it is a good stepping stone.
I am trying to create a membership only site in Framer, where I can have people create accounts, and choose subscriptions. To do this, I found a third party software called Hound. This lets me create a login, signup, logout and settings component and handels all the backend for me.
The way it works is that I can block certain webpages for members that are on a certain subscription. But I want to create a master login credential, as in some login credentials which don't need to be on a subscription but can still access all the pages on the site. What I thought of doing was making like a "free" plan an enrolling the account I wan to be the master on that plan, but when you select a subscription on Hound, this is what happens:

All subscriptions become visible to the user.
So essentially, my question is: is it possible to have this master login credential with any other framework that can be easily integrated with framer and is free to use? I found out about Auth0, but I can't find any tutorials on it online on how to integrate it with framer and get it working. Any advice on this will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
